# Using _DIR_ vs Manually Detailing Path in PHP

Tags: php, file, path

I did a `php` tutorial which taught me to do things like this:

```
defined('DS')?null:define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
defined('PUBLIC_PATH')?null:define('PUBLIC_PATH','http://www.myurl.com/');
defined('SITE_ROOT')?null:define('SITE_ROOT',DS.'home'.DS.'public_html'.DS.'myhome');
defined('LIB_PATH')?null:define('LIB_PATH',DS.'home'.DS.'public_html'.DS.'includes');
```

Then I can do things like:

```
require_once (LIB_PATH. DS .'initialize.php');
```

I was just told I could be using `_DIR_` instead of manually spelling out my paths like above.

Is this true?  What are the advantage/downsides of each way?

Comment: you don't have to worry about `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` anymore. you can use `/` forward slash for `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` on windows machine also.

Comment: @bansi  Good to know.  But better safe for backwards compatibility?

Comment: @KickingLettuce Only if you plan on developing a solution that might be used on an older version of PHP.

Comment: see http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: I would prefer to use `dirname(__FILE__)` or `__DIR__` for `SITE_ROOT` and just a simple `/` for `PUBLIC_PATH` instead of hard coding the locations. It becomes easier when you deploy your script to the production server or as a sub domain.

Comment: What about for a library path up one directory in an `includes` folder? `require_once __DIR__ . "/../includes/initialize.php";`  This works .. but does this seem proper to spell out the path on every page?

Comment: i don't mean to use it in every file/line. you can define it if you want a easier name. but if you just say `require_once 'includes/initialize.php';` PHP will include the file which is in the include folder under current script's folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be two questions here:

- How to generate paths (manually vs. discovered)
- Cost/Benefit of using / vs DS

**Generating Paths**

The short answer is that discovered paths are more versatile than manual paths, as with anything hard coded. If you move the application, you have to revisit each manual path and modify it for a new location.

On the other hand, if you bootstrap your application from a known file location, you can use `__DIR__` in that file to anchor all the discovered paths you need. If you move the whole application, it simply continues to work.

**Directory Separators**

You can use the forward slash on windows these days. But there are some edge cases where you probably don't want to. Particularly if you are going to be matching paths later. `realpath` will always return backslashes on windows and forward slashes on *nix. Thus, you can create two strings that do not match (due to slashes) that will access the same file on windows, fortunately you can't really do that on *nix.

However, you can use forward slashes with `realpath` and always get the appropriate separator regardless of the system you are on.

**Best Practice**

Use discovery wherever possible, and when discovering relative paths, wrap them in a `realpath` call:

*SomeApplicationRootFile.php*

```
/**
 * This makes our life easier when dealing with paths. Everything is relative
 * to the application root now.
 */
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));

defined('DS')?null:define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
defined('SITE_ROOT')?null:define('SITE_ROOT', __DIR__);
defined('LIB_PATH')?null:define('LIB_PATH', 
    realpath(__DIR__ . '/../home/public_html/includes');
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer.  I like the end result you posted.  Is this line necessary? `chdir(dirname(__DIR__));`  I'm pretty sure I have a feeling why you are doing but you can elaborate on that?  Seems like it's just setting you up to the local directory if the "end" file that is including this file is in a different one.  Is that why?

Comment: Aye, it allows you to execute command line scripts from a known path as well. So if you shell out for anything, you know where you are shelling too.